# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jinja2

I am a beginner to Python web development. I was practicing UPDATE operation. Problem is occurring when I am try to fetch a value from text box and store it in a variable in python. The code I've written I am showing below:

```
mysql> desc sample;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EMAIL | varchar(70) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PHONE | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my database

```
{% for col in students %}
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="Id" value="{{col.0}}" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="n" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="{{col.1}}" />
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="e" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{col.2}}" />
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" class="form-control" name="phone" id="p" placeholder="Phone" value="{{col.3}}" />
```

```py
@app.route('/update', methods=['POST','GET'])
def update():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        id_val = request.method['id']
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']

        #Updating values
        cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
        cur.execute('UPDATE sample SET name=%s, email=%s, phone=%s WHERE id=%s',(name,email,phone,id_val))
        flash("Data Updated Successfully !!")
        mysql.get_db().commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

This is my Python code.
The problem is occuring **id_val = request.method['id']** in this line. It's telling **TypeError: string indices must be integers**.

What is needed to be corrected here ? Please help me out

Comment: Shouldn't it be `request.form['id']` instead of `request.method['id']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

`request.method['id']`

which evaluates to `'POST'['id']`.

`request.method` gives you `'POST'` string and `['id']` tries to slice it using index.

As the `'id'` is not an index, it is giving telling you this -

> TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Try changing the `request.method['id']` to `request.form['id']`. This should work.

Comment: thanks dude should have seen that my bad